# Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] Problem with Contract

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I've sent the transaction - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xbecb36319d806edc3617abcbeb1f95e7215cb205dc180088f225c1addd82086f to the contract address and it got reverted.

Could someone explain me why?

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;
```

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Waterfall {
    using SafeMath for uint;

```
struct User {
    address payable addr;
    uint amount;
}

address payable public owner;
User[] public users;
uint public totalUsers = 0;
uint public feePercentage = 10;
uint public payoutPercentage = 10;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function join() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "Investment must be at least 1 ether");
    users.push(User(msg.sender, msg.value));
    totalUsers += 1;

    uint fee = msg.value.mul(feePercentage).div(100);
    owner.transfer(fee);

    uint position = 0;
    while(position < totalUsers) {
        uint payout = users[position].amount.mul(payoutPercentage).div(100);
        if(payout > address(this).balance){
            break;
        }
        users[position].addr.transfer(payout);
        position += 1;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an empty transaction with 1.1 Ethers without targeting any specific function.

As you are using Solidity version 0.6.8 you need to have either the `receive` function (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) or `fallback` function (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#fallback-function) in your contract to catch transactions which do not call any specific function. As you don't have those the transaction fails.

Either specify that you want to call the `join` function or add a `receive/fallback` function in your contract.